# Kdb - selecting by column where the symbol is two words

Tags: kdb, qsqlquery

I have a table with a column "counterparty". The datatype is a symbol. however there is two separate words in the format of:
"enlist`XXX XXX"
I am selecting where counterpart = XXX XXX. Any ideas on how to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be worth using an each-right iterator with `in`, assuming I've understood you right.

```
q)t: ([] a: 1 2; b: (enlist `$"xx xxxx"; (`$"xxxx xxxx"; `$"xxxx xxxx")))
q)t
a b                   
----------------------
1 ,`xx xxxx           
2 `xxxx xxxx`xxxx xxxx
q)select from t where (`$"xx xxxx") in/: b
a b      
---------
1 xx xxxx
```